# Deactive bootstrap active label click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have several groups with a selection of three buttons. I'm trying to make it so that when someone selects the N/A button, it disables the other two buttons.  When the N/A button is deselected, the other two buttons are enabled.  I have it working on my machine, that the other two buttons are colored as disabled, and have the "disabled" attribute set properly.  The problem is, that the buttons/labels can still be clicked on and set the label to active.

I'm having trouble getting my JSFiddle to operate the same as on my machine.  It won't disable the other two buttons on the initial N/A click, but it may just be something with JSFiddle.  Here is my code, if you want to try it on your own machine:

https://jsfiddle.net/trout0525/huz8macm/7/

```
<div id="plan-wrapper">
    <div class="row plan-title-row">
        <div class="col-lg-6" id="plan-title">
            Loading...
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="pull-right" id="countdown">
                Countdown
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-bottom: 4px;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row" id="master-progress">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="plan-file-title" style="margin: 0 0 4px 5px;"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#planTeam">Team</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#planResources">Resources</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#planStatus">Status</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" style="background-color: white; padding: 10px; border-left: 1px solid #ddd; border-right: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
                <div id="planTeam" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                </div>
                <div id="planResources" class="tab-pane fade">
                </div>
                <div id="planStatus" class="tab-pane fade">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you minimize the code in the fiddle to only what is needed?

Comment: Sorry.  There was some extra JavaScript variables and a for loop that didn't need to be there.  Here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/trout0525/huz8macm/8/

Comment: Note: I only included the HTML code here in Stack Overflow, but JSFiddle has some JS and CSS that I believe would not have fit in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Got it done on JSFiddle with removal of typos and debugging through developer console, yet it's currently with Chrome, not IE:

https://jsfiddle.net/trout0525/huz8macm/9/

```
$(".btn-group .btn").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $selectedButton = $(this),
        $panelDefault = $selectedButton.closest('.panel-default'),
        $controlPanel = $panelDefault.find('.panel-heading .pull-right'),
        parent = $selectedButton.closest('.panel-default').attr('data-stepId'),
        stepId = $selectedButton.closest('li').attr('id'),
        spcStat = $selectedButton.attr('id').match(/^(.*?)\d+$/)[1];

    var buttonIsActive = $selectedButton.hasClass('active'),
        buttonIsDisabled = $selectedButton.attr('disabled');

    if ( buttonIsActive || buttonIsDisabled ) {
        $selectedButton.removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $selectedButton.addClass('active');
    }

    if ($selectedButton.hasClass('not-applicable')) {
        var naIsActive = $selectedButton.hasClass('active'),
            allButtons = $selectedButton.closest('.btn-group');

        if (naIsActive) {
            $selectedButton.siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(allButtons)
                .find('.btn_draft_complete')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                .attr('title', 'Disabled. To enable: deselect N/A for this substep')
                .find('input')
                .css('point-events', 'auto');
            $(allButtons)
                .find('.btn_done')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                .attr('title', 'Disabled. To enable: deselect N/A for this substep')
                .find('input')
                .css('point-events', 'auto');
        } else {
            $(allButtons)
                .find('.btn_draft_complete')
                .removeAttr('disabled')
                .attr('title', 'Mark step as Draft Complete')
                .find('input')
                .removeAttr('disabled')
            $(allButtons)
                .find('.btn_done')
                .removeAttr('disabled')
                .attr('title', 'Mark step as Draft Complete')
                .find('input')
                .removeAttr('disabled')
        }
    }
});
```